# what will happen if we copy more data from source to destination using memcpy?

Tags: c, arrays, memcpy

I have the following code:

```
int dst[5];
int src[100];

// assign value to array src
memcpy(&dst[0], &src[0], sizeof(int) * 100);
```

what will happen in this case? will only the first 5 elements is copied to array `dst`? 
or the program will crash?

Comment: If you're lucky the program will crash

Comment: C *always* assumes that you know what you are doing and that your *really* did mean the silly thing you said...and that would be a very silly thing, indeed.

Comment: Size of `dst` array is just `5` < `100`, by copying 100 into `dst[]` (by `memcpy(&dst[0], &src[0], sizeof(int) * 100);`) your code will causes [buffer overrun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) problem that will causes run time error (actually its behavior undefined), in worst case you program can crash

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Actually, that's the **best** case.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth :) :)...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This invokes **undefined behaviour**.  Anything could happen.

In practice, what will probably happen is that memory outside of `dst` will be overwritten, trashing something else, and therefore corrupting the state of your program.  The best-case scenario is that this causes your program to crash.

Comment: I tried this hoping I would see a unicorn or something... but I always get a crash.,